# hyperref and loading accents

Tags: hyperref, accents

Here's my MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{this produces warnings : é}

é % or \phantom{é} this 'loads' é ?

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{this does not produce warnings : é}

\end{document}
```

Took me a while to find why only the first `\addcontentsline` got warnings, but it appears I can't use accentuated characters as long as I haven't used them anywhere else... Is there a fix for this ? (other than the `\phantom{é}` I currently have at the beginning of my document...)

Using Miktex 2.9, I have updated all my packages recently.

Note : it works if I use `\'e` instead of `é`, but for various reasons I need the actual `é` character.

Comment: The simplest solution is not using `utf8x`, but `utf8`. Not related, but important: don't specify the `pdftex` option.

Comment: @egreg : I'll try removing the utf8x. Can't remember why I added the x a while ago, can you think of a reason ? Also why do I need to remove pdftex ?

Comment: Packages such as `hyperref` and `graphicx` are able to guess the right option (if it should be `dvips` or `pdftex`) and it's best not to specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hyperref` needs to be prepared for unicode characters such as the direct use of `é` etc. Typing `é` somewhere in the document will do so for all following occurences, but not for the previous on. Ideally, it should appear in the preamble, but this is impossible, since there mustn't be typesetting.

The remedy is to 'fake' the output of `é` (and possible other unicode characters) in the preamble.

This can be achieved with `\PrerenderUnicode{é}` in the preamble.

By the way: There is an explicit warning in the bookmarks if `\PrerenderUnicode` is missing and you are advised to add `\PrerenderUnicode` in the preamble ;-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,unicode]{hyperref}

\PrerenderUnicode{é}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{this produces warnings : é}

%é % or \phantom{é} this 'loads' é ?

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{this does not produce warnings : é}

\end{document}
```

I've omitted a screenshot since this doesn't need such one.

---

To clearify: Here is the warning produced in ToC and bookmarks, if `\PreenderUnicode` isn't applied in the preamble.

[image]

Comment: can't see that warning though. do I have to use \usepackage{bookmark} ?

Comment: @imj: No, I've used the document above. I will show a screen shot from Adobe Reader output in a few moments

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks a lot. Interesting place to put a Latex warning :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `utf8` instead of `utf8x`; in the past there were reasons to prefer the latter (not when writing in French), but the issues (with Greek) have been solved. There's no point in using `utf8x` and `ucs` (that's implicitly loaded), because it's just more complicated than `utf8` and gives essentially no advantage.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{no warning here : é}

é % or \phantom{é} this 'loads' é ?

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{neither here : é}

\end{document}
```

[image]