# Problem with accents package

Tags: packages, accents

There seems to be a clash between `hyperref` and `accents`. Reduced MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Estimate on $\tilde{\alpha}$}
\end{document}
```

Commenting out either of `\usepackage{accents}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}` removes the error (but does not solve the problem).

---

I am trying to use accents package in my document and when I include

```
\usepackage{accents}
```

to my original document, I got an error as

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>    
>                     \HyPsd@@LetCommand 
>   l.205 \begin{lemma}
>   !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I tried to open a fresh document and copied the initial parts (up to `\begin{document}`).
I am including `\usepackage{accents}` to same line as in my original document and there is no error.

I don't really know what to include here but I can provide any information that might be useful.

Let me add;
**End of Log File**

```
(./epsilon_closeloop.toc
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
)
\tf@toc=\write6
\openout6 = `epsilon_closeloop.toc'.

 [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmtt on input line 187.

 (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd
File: t1lmtt.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again> 
                   \HyPsd@@LetCommand 
l.205 \begin{lemma}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15098 strings out of 494923
 238621 string characters out of 6180741
 684258 words of memory out of 5000000
 18040 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 54559 words of font info for 52 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 175 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,18n,8735p,922b,742s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

**Lemma part**

```
\subsection{Estimate on $\mc{W}_2(\mu_t^{N,\a,\t\a},\bar{\mu}_t^{N,\a})$}

\begin{lemma}  
  \begin{equation}  
    \frac{1}{N}\sum_j |X_t^{N,\a,\t\a,j} - \bar{X}_t^{N,\a,j}|^2 \leq
    \delta^2 + \int_0^t \mc{W}_2^2(\mu_s^{N,\a,\t\a},\mu_s^\a)  
  \end{equation}  
\end{lemma}
```

**Lemma part End**

**Full Preamble**

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{mathtools} %%used for \usetagform{roman}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=teal,%
  urlcolor=teal%
}%


\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for proof environment.
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{showlabels}%For writing purposes. Comment at the end.

\usepackage[left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\weak}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\ind}[1]{{\bf 1}_{\left\{ {#1} \right\}} }
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
%% \newcommand{\an}{\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}}

%% \DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\supp}{supp}


%% Stochastic Specific
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\t{\tilde}
\def\b{\overline} % First defined for bar.
\def\h{\hat}
\def\ub{\underline} %First defined for underbar, however underbar
                    %converts to text mode!

%% \newcommand{\ub}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}} %%Requires accents package.


\newtagform{roman}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}]()

\title{Close Loop}
\date{\today}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} %%included in init
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} %%included in init
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma} 

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition} %%included in init
\newtheorem{note}{Note} %%included in init
\newtheorem{example}{Example} %%included in init 
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption} %%included in init
```

**Full Preamble**

Comment: Welcome! Can you perhaps try to share the log file of the run that causes an error? Or just try to produce a minimal document where you do as you describe above but also add the lemma and the stuff right before the lemma?

Comment: It fails on \subsection{Estimate on $\mc{W}_2(\mu_t^{N,\a,\t\a},\bar{\mu}_t^{N,\a})$}.

Comment: You can reduce the problematic example to `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Estimate on $\tilde{\alpha}$}
\end{document}`. Dropping either `\usepackage{accents}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}` makes the error go away (but does of course not solve the problem). I will edit your question by adding this MWE at the beginning but you can of course reverse the edit (yet I think it will be cleaner to remove everything else, at least temporarily).

Comment: There seem to be some related posts such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257052 but I do not know enough about this to turn this in a real answer.

Comment: I stop after this comment. Workaround: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\oldtilde\tilde
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Estimate on $\oldtilde{\alpha}$}
\end{document}`. So you could add `\let\t\tilde` *before* loading `\usepackage{accents}` and remove `\def\t{\tilde}` from your document. This should remove this error. Having said this, I would like to discourage you from defining one-letter macros in the way you do.

Comment: Thank you very much for reducing, editing and workaround.

Comment: It is a bad idea to do `\def\a`, `\def\t`, `\def\b`, `\def\h`, etc. You should initialize one letter macros with `\newcommand` and if that gives errors because they're already defined, don't redefine them, they are most likely needed for font/input specific stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the problematic redefinition of `\a`, `\t` and `\b`, and the misplaced `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{showlabels}` (`hyperref` should be the last package in the preamble in general, but there are some exceptions, like `showlabels` which must be loaded after `hyperref`).

To still use the definitions of `accents` (because I guess that's what you want, when you load it), but have a functional `hyperref` with the macros of `accents` in captions, section headings, etc. you have to make sure that `hyperref` doesn't use the macros it can't handle to create bookmarks. This can be done on a manual basis with `\texorpdfstring`, but I'd suggest setting up rules directly for the offending macros so that you don't have to care for them later. For this `hyperref` provides the `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` macro, which we use to locally redefine `\tilde` and `\bar`, so that for PDF-bookmarks the standard version is used, but for the rest of your document the versions provided by `accents`.

(In the following I removed everything that isn't directly related to the problem at hand)

```latex
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\let\preAccentstilde\tilde
\let\preAccentsbar\bar
\usepackage{accents}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands
  {%
    \let\tilde\preAccentstilde
    \let\bar\preAccentsbar
  }

\usepackage{showlabels}%For writing purposes. Comment at the end.

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}


%% Stochastic Specific
\newcommand\h{\hat}

\title{Close Loop}
\date{\today}
\author{Melih Iseri}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\subsection{Estimate on $\mc{W}_2(\mu_t^{N,\alpha,\tilde{\alpha}},\bar{\mu}_t^{N,\alpha})$}
\end{document}
```

Note that while this does solve the problem and makes your document at least compilable, it's still best to manually clean bookmarks using `\texorpdfstring`, e.g., instead of

```latex
\section{Some section $\alpha$}
```

use

```latex
\section{\texorpdfstring{Some section $\alpha$}{Some section a}}
```

Comment: Is it ok to define them as 
\let\olda\a
\renewcommand\a{\alpha}
Notations are messy and one letter definitions are a great simplification.
Thank you.

Comment: @Jo' no, that's not ok, as that doesn't set up anything that tells the internals to use `\olda` instead of `\a` when `\a` would be used. I'd suggest you check whether your editor of choice allows to create shortcuts (e.g., in my VIM, if I type `\`a` this becomes `\alpha`).