# problem with \mathaccent when \usepackage{hyperref} is loaded

Tags: packages, debugging

Here is a `MWE`.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\.}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\+}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}


%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Let $\.f(x) = (x+2a)^3 -27 a^2 x$, where $a\ge 0$. 
By sketching  $\.f(x)$, show that $\.f(x)\ge 0$ for~$x \ge0$. 



\end{document}
```

I think I have located the problem now. But not sure why this happens.

Everything is **fine** without `\usepackage{hyperref}`. But when I have loaded the package, it can't compile with `latex myfile.tex`. Error message says

> Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. \add@accent ...@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent #1 #2\egroup \spacefactor ...

I am using `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` to compile.

Comment: You may get lucky, but I doubt anyone will be able to guess without more information.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see `MWE` now. I have made it.

Comment: don't redefine core latex commands unless you are _sure_ it is safe!!!!!!

Comment: `\.` is a fundamental accent command used explictly and implicitly throughout latex's text encoding handing. If you choose to redefine it you need to expect to redefine a lot of code in a lot of packages that handle any kind of tex writing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using `'input` to put a lot of exisiting tex files into one document, so I don't have to compile them seperately. I am trying to add a bookmark, so I want to define a new command to get it done. But if it can't even load the hyperref package, how can i add bookmark?

Comment: no you had already broken latex by redefining `\.` you just got lucky and avoided an error, with hyperref you got less lucky but the error is redefining `\.` just use a different name and don't use `\renewcommand` unless you are sure of the consequences. That is exactly why `\newcommand` gives an error if you use an existing name, to stop this kind of error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK then. I will try a different approach to get a work around. The original/existing files goes back to 1986 and it was used throughout.

Comment: it is of course possible to patch hyperref not to check this but (as a maintainer of hyperref and of latex) I honestly wouldn't want to suggest that in a public forum as people would copy the code and not read these comments (no one reads documentation:-)  redefining `\.` really is wrong and just a simple edit of the source files to rename it to anything else is what I would strongly recommend. But leave the question open someone else is bound to answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, of course I understand. Thanks again for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522159/194703) is related?

Comment: someone who wasn't me might for example suggest moving the renewcommand \. line after hyperref is included.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I have tried it and didn't seem to work.

Comment: There is seldom the need of having command (re)definitions before having loaded all packages. It's much better to section the preamble into package loading, settings and personal command definitions. It will be easier to find your way into the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason latex has `\newcommand` which generates an error if over-writing an existing command is to make this kind of error less likely. `\.` is a core latex command and shouldn't be redefined (unless you are redefining all of latex's text handling, eg for unicode tex variants rather than classic tex etc.) Redefining it will break documents even if they do not have `\.` explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\emph{Ġood}

\renewcommand{\.}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}


\emph{Less Ġood}

\end{document}
```

Generates no error but produces

[image]

However if you really must do this and simply changing the command to any other name is not a possibility, simply move the `\renewcommand\.` line after `\usepackage{hyperref}` the latex text handling is then still broken but hyperref's checks on accent commands are over-written as well so adding hyperref doesn't make things even worse.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\newcommand{\+}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\.}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{#1}}}% not recommended, use a different name!


\begin{document}

Let $\.f(x) = (x+2a)^3 -27 a^2 x$, where $a\ge 0$. 
By sketching  $\.f(x)$, show that $\.f(x)\ge 0$ for~$x \ge0$. 



\end{document}
```

[image]