# Use accented characters in bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, accents, bookmarks

I am trying to generate my own recipe collection. I've got my inspiration from [An Aesthetically Pleasing Recipe Book Template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366229/an-aesthetically-pleasing-recipe-book-template). It is really similar but I've tweaked a few things. So far, it's working well but I found something that bugs me and I do not know how to solve it.

I wanted to generate a pdf file from my collection with easy access to the recipe so I used the `hyperref` package and its `pdfbookmark` command. It works until I am trying to use accented characters in that command. It seems that those characters are breaking the bookmark rendering.

- If I remove the accented characters, it works.
- If I replace `é` by `` \`e ``, it does not work.
- I've tried to use `utf8x` with `\PrerenderUnicode{é}` instead of `utf8` as mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257052/70112), but it does not work.
- I've tried to use the `unicode` option in the `hyperref` package as mentioned in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41662/70112), but it does not work.

Here is a minimal (kind of) working example of my collection:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, headheight=15pt, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\newcommand{\group}[1]{
    \pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}
}

\newcommand{\recipe}[1]{%
    \newpage%
    \pagestyle{fancy}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize{\textbf{#1}}}%
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{}%
    \pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{\pdfmdfivesum{#1}}%
    \section*{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
    \group{Boissons}
    \recipe{Dark \& stormy}
    \recipe{Limonana}

    \group{Desserts}
    \recipe{Tiramisu}
    \recipe{X-mas cake}

    \group{Poisson}
    \recipe{Gravlax de saumon au miel et à la moutarde}
    \recipe{Pain de saumon}

    \group{Viande}
    \recipe{Boulets de Liège}
    \recipe{Poulet à l'ananas}
    \recipe{Ragoût à la joue de bœuf et lard paysan}
\end{document}
```

What should I do to allows the bookmarks to work properly with accents?

Comment: Just add the instruciton `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble.

Comment: @Mico I've tried that as well with no luck :/

Comment: use `\pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{\pdfmdfivesum{\detokenize{#1}}}`

Comment: in no way geometry can affect hyperref here. In your second example you removed the bookmark package and that has an effect, as bookmark changes the pdfbookmark command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer arf! you're right. I may have been to quick to judge. I'll modify what I've wrote. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Do you get errors? How are you compiling? And is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry if I mislead you. It's working. But I was wrong about the reason why it was working now. You were right about my faulty reasoning. To answer your questions, I do not have errors now. I am compiling with pdflatex inside texmaker. My tex is up-to-date since it's the latest available in Arch Linux repositories.

Comment: well it should work with the bookmark package too, but you then need \detokenize or the links will be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you (a) load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`, (b) simplify the way you load the `hyperref` package, and (c) not load the `bookmark` and `inputenc` packages unless your TeX distributions is several years old and hasn't been updated in more than three years.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, headheight=15pt, hmargin=1cm, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % <-- new
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref} % <-- simplified

\newcommand{\group}[1]{\pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\recipe}[1]{%
    \newpage%
    \pagestyle{fancy}%
    \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize\textbf{#1}}%
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}%
    \fancyfoot[C]{}%
    \pdfbookmark[1]{#1}{\pdfmdfivesum{#1}}%
    \section*{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\group{Boissons}
    \recipe{Dark \& stormy}
    \recipe{Limonana}

\group{Desserts}
    \recipe{Tiramisu}
    \recipe{X-mas cake}

\group{Poisson}
    \recipe{Gravlax de saumon au miel et à la moutarde}
    \recipe{Pain de saumon}

\group{Viande}
    \recipe{Boulets de Liège}
    \recipe{Poulet à l'ananas}
    \recipe{Ragoût à la joue de bœuf et lard paysan}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the bookmarks option is not the same as loading the bookmark package which quite extends and improves the bookmark handling.

Comment: I'm not sure why discouraging `bookmarks`, which is generally better than the `bookmarks` option to `hyperref` and was written for the purpose of improving bookmark management.

Comment: @egreg -- I use Acrobat Reader (AR) as my pdf viewer, on a MacOS 12.2 "Big Sur" system. If I follow your (implicit?) suggestion, i.e., if I do *not* specify the `bookmarks` option when loading `hyperref` but do load the `bookmark` package, then opening the pdf file in AR and clicking on one of the bookmark tabs does absolutely nothing. In contrast, with the answer I posted above, I *do* get the desired behavior. That is, incidentally, why I posted the answer the way I did. Maybe other pdf viewers behave differently?

Comment: you write as comment "simplified" and don't really explain why you remove bookmark. To me it makes the impression as if you think it is unneeded. But actually it slows down the compilation, (without bookmark, you need two to get the bookmarks), and you loose the additional features of the package.

Comment: And regarding the bookmarks doing nothing: That's why I wrote that \detokenize is needed, at least for the bookmarks with accent.

Comment: well you are removing options the user wanted. hidelinks and unicode are not set by default in a current hyperref with pdflatex. On the other side bookmarks is true, so is actually unneeded.

Comment: @Mico please believe me. hyperref sets `\Hy@bookmarkstrue` in line 287. Using the option doesn't change anything. But it does change something if you use `\usepackage{bookmark}` or not.

Answer (score 3):

The rendering of the bookmarks in your example should work fine if you compile with a current tex system and the pdf viewer can handle unicode.

What doesn't work are the actual links: the bookmark package and hyperref have slightly different methods and settings to handle commands in destination names and so create different names in your example. So you need to use `\detokenize` to make them to simple strings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
xxx
\newpage 
aaa
\pdfbookmark[1]{1. Ragoût à la joue de bœuf et lard paysan}
  {\pdfmdfivesum{zzzRagoût à la joue de bœuf et lard paysan}}


\pdfbookmark[1]{2. Ragoût à la joue de bœuf et lard paysan}
  {\pdfmdfivesum{\detokenize{xxxRagoût à la joue de bœuf et lard paysan}}}
\end{document}
```

In the first bookmark will give a warning

```
 pdfTeX warning (dest): name{68378F0B27FA693E17106CB4A2941F21.
 1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

and jump to the first page, but the second will work.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the sectioning commands.  The `hyperref` package will generate bookmarks for all sections, subsections, and so on, down to the current `bookmarksdepth` (which by default is the `\tocdepth`).

It lets you use all the standard commands for section formatting, create a table of contents page in addition to the PDF bookmarks, and make references to a `\label`.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn if the current font is missing a glyph
\usepackage[letterpaper, headheight=15pt, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks,bookmarksdepth,unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{libertinus} % Or your fonts of choice.
\usepackage{microtype}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % Create bookmarks for subsections (recipes)

\newcommand{\group}[1]{%
  \clearpage%
  \section{#1}%
  \markright{}%
}

\newcommand{\recipe}[1]{%
  \pagebreak%
  \subsection*{#1}%
  \markright{#1}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}%
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textsc{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize{\textbf{\rightmark}}}%
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}%
\fancyfoot[C]{}%

\begin{document}
    \group{Boissons}\label{gr:boissons}
    \recipe{Dark \& stormy}\label{rx:darknstormy}
    \recipe{Limonana}\label{rx:limonana}

    \group{Desserts}\label{gr:desserts}
    \recipe{Tiramisu}\label{rx:tiramisu}
    \recipe{X-mas cake}\label{rx:xmascake}

    \group{Poisson}\label{gr:poisson}
    \recipe{Gravlax de saumon au miel et à la moutarde}\label{rx:gravlax}
    \recipe{Pain de saumon}\label{rx:painsaumon}

    \group{Viande}\label{gr:viande}
    \recipe{Boulets de Liège}\label{rx:liegs}
    \recipe{Poulet à l'ananas}\label{rx:lananas}
    \recipe{Ragoût à la joue de bœuf et lard paysan}\label{rx:ragoutpaysan}
\end{document}
```

That code is compatible with both LuaLaTeX and PDFTeX.  I personally recommend LuaTeX except when a publisher forces you to use PDFTeX, but use what you prefer.

Comment: `\let\tocdepth=2`? Are you sure?

Comment: @egreg No. I had it working earlier, but that looks like a goof.

Comment: Possibly `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`?

Comment: @egreg Yep. Was testing. Thanks for catching the mistake.

Comment: @egreg Also needs the explicit `bookmarksdepth` option anyway, so I might as well have set it there.